# Run Windows Program While Not Logged In

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-services, windows-server-2003

I've recently become "reacquainted" with Windows and I'm also new to .NET & C#.  I'm trying to figure out a way to run a program on a Windows 2003 machine at all times (i.e. it runs when no one is logged in and automatically starts on server boot).  I think I'm overcomplicating the problem and getting myself stuck.

This program, called Job.exe, normally runs in a GUI, but I do have the option of running it from the command line with parameters.

Because of the "always on" part, the first thing that comes to mind is to create a service.  Ridiculously, I'm getting stuck on how exactly to run the executable (Job.exe) from within my Service1.cs file (did I mention I'm new to c#?).

A couple other points I'm stuck on regarding creating a service are how/where to configure desktop interaction since I want Job.exe to run totally in the background.  Also, since `OnStart` is supposed to return to the OS when finished, I'm a little confused as to where I should put the code to execute the program; do I place it in my `OnStart` method or create a method that I then call from `OnStart`?

Last question on creating a service is about the parameters.  Job.exe accepts two parameters in total, one static and one dynamic (i.e. could be defined via the service properties dialog in the services management console).  I'd like to be able to create multiple instances of the service specifying a different dynamic parameter for each one.  Also, the dynamic parameter should be able to accept a string array.

I'm sure there are options outside of creating a service, so I will take any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you may be over-complicating the problem, you may consider using the Task Scheduler to run your application.

Using the Task Scheduler will allow you to make a "regular" desktop application which is arguably a simpler approach than creating your own service. Also, the Task Scheduler has many options that fit the requirements you touched on.

Comment: If it fits your use case, this may be a great approach. You might need to modify the application itself to check the property that I mention in my answer so it knows whether or not to display a UI.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach might be to create a service, reference the application's assembly, and call it's `Main()` method to start the application.  The application itself could use [Environment.UserInteractive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userinteractive.aspx) to detect if it is running as a service or as a desktop application.

One thing to watch out for, as you mention, is that the Start method of a service (and the other control methods) is expected to return immediately-ish (in the timespan of the "Starting Service..." dialog) so you'll need to spin up a thread to run the main method.  Something like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => { MyApplication.Application.Main("firstParam", "secondParam"); });
t.Start();
```

The params could come from a file and the service can be configured with the file name as a parameter (see [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ankithakur/Passing_parameters_to_Windows_Services10062006000204AM/Passing_parameters_to_Windows_Services.aspx) for one of many examples on how to do that), or the service could be configured as you mentioned to take the parameters and pass them along to the application's main method.  These are both viable approaches.  Either way, only one instance of a service can be running at a time, so you'd need to register the service multiple times with different names to configure different parameters.

Comment: This will be very helpful for some other projects I have in mind.  Thanks for the reply!